# How to Get list of site collections in a web application using JSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, csom

I have got a requirement like want to fetch the details of all the site collections in a web application either using JSOM or .net managed client object model?

Please provide me those details.

Thanks in advance

-Thanks,
Sasi kumar Reddy

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see the objects you need to perform the action (like SPWebApplication) are not exposed via the client object model (or REST / OData).

Unfortunately, the standard web services provide no help as well, "If you want the list of all Site collections or WebApps, there is no way at all using any of the SharePoint Web Services." as stated [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63861/Limitations-of-SharePoint-Web-Services).

If you need to do that from the client side, you should create and deploy your wrapper objects on the server side, for example, you can create your a custom web service / OData endpoint, or even extend the client object model as described [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/managed-client-object-model-internals-creating-custom-client-om-extensions/) (managed) or [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/ecmascript-client-object-model-internals-creating-custom-client-om-extensions/) (JavaScript).